# How to build an imagem using Boot2Docker on Windows?

Tags: windows, docker, boot2docker

I have my local development files on `G:\www\project` and my `Dockerfile` is placed in `G:\www\project\Dockerfile`.

Currently there's no way I can do `docker build -t app .`, my Dockerfile is like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.10

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y --force-yes && apt-get -y install software-properties-common --force-yes
RUN locale-gen pt_BR.UTF-8 
ENV LANG pt_BR.UTF-8 
ENV LC_ALL pt_BR.UTF-8

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:nginx/stable 
RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php5
RUN apt-get -y install nginx php5-fpm php5-mysql php-apc php5-mcrypt php5-gd

RUN echo "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" >> /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini

ADD https://raw.github.com/h5bp/server-configs-nginx/master/h5bp/location/expires.conf /etc/nginx/conf/expires.conf 
ADD https://raw.github.com/h5bp/server-configs-nginx/master/h5bp/directive-only/x-ua-compatible.conf /etc/nginx/conf/x-ua-compatible.conf 
ADD https://raw.github.com/h5bp/server-configs-nginx/master/h5bp/location/cross-domain-fonts.conf /etc/nginx/conf/cross-domain-fonts.conf 
ADD https://raw.github.com/h5bp/server-configs-nginx/master/h5bp/location/protect-system-files.conf /etc/nginx/conf/protect-system-files.conf

RUN mkdir /srv/www

ADD ./docker/default /etc/nginx/sites-available/default 
ADD ./docker/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

RUN sed -i -e '/access_log/d' /etc/nginx/conf/expires.conf 
RUN sed -i -e 's/^listen =.*/listen = \/var\/run\/php5-fpm.sock/' /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

ADD ./docker/start.sh /start.sh

ADD ./application /srv/www/application 
ADD ./bower_components /srv/www/bower_components 
ADD ./content /srv/www/content 
ADD ./javascripts /srv/www/javascripts 
ADD ./modules /srv/www/modules 
ADD ./stylsheets /srv/www/stylesheets 
ADD ./system /srv/www/system 
ADD ./index.php /srv/www/index.php

EXPOSE 80 443
RUN chmod +x /start.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/start.sh"]
```

I've seen workarounds for OSX but none for Windows. Tried to install VirtualBox Guest Additions to the tinycorelinux, but it doesn't mount the image to sr0

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is no currently supported Docker client for windows (though its on its way)

And iirc, Boot2Docker 1.3 is hard coded to assume your Users dir is on `C:` :/

so the best solution to get there quickly, is to scp the files to the vm, and then run the build there.

(from `G:\Users\project`)

`$ scp * docker@$(boot2docker ip):~/
$ boot2docker ssh
$$ docker build -t app .
$$ docker run --rm -it app bash`